# PHP - Converting HTML Table to CSV adds empty lines

Tags: php, html, excel, csv, utf-8

I have a simple PHP script that converts a HTML Table into a CSV file. Due to UTF-8 converting reasons I added `fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");` and everything works finde besides of additional empty lines (every second one) while opening the CSV files in MS Excel (Mac and Windows - latest versions).

Opening this with Macs Preview doesn't show that empty lines - and when I remove the `fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");`it also doesn't add the empty lines but then of course my text is destroyed.

This is my PHP script:

```php
<?php

include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

$table = file_get_contents('hotel.html');
$html = str_get_html($table);

//Generate the CSV file header
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pkb.csv');


$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");


foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) 
{
    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('th') as $row) 
    {
        $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td, ';');
    $td = array();
    foreach( $element->find('td') as $row) 
    {
       $td [] = $row->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td, ';');
}
fclose($fp);

?>
```

The HTML Table is quite common:

```html
<table>
<th>
</th>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

And the converted CSV opened with Excel looks like that:

[CSV opened in Excel with empty rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFjIC.jpg)

Maybe you find my mistake which generates these additional empty lines.
Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is duplicate iterations

```
foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) {
    $td = [];
    foreach( $element->find('th') as $row) {
        $td[] = $row->plaintext;
    }

    if (!empty($td)) {
        fputcsv($fp, $td, ';');
    }

    $td = [];
    foreach( $element->find('td') as $row) {
       $td[] = $row->plaintext;
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $td, ';');
}
```

Something like that is a simple fix, but I would suggest rewriting the entire foreach.

Comment: Hi decanus, thanks for your fast reaction. I also thought about that, but there is definitely no empty value in my table structure.

Comment: @neilhurt I found the issue, its the first foreach. When you foreach on th. <th> only exists in one row. But you iterate and add an empty td for every row. See my edited answer

Comment: Wow, that's it. Thanks a lot decanus